# Vector grid in QGIS3 - Can I change the order of row number?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

When creating a grid (e.g. dx=15,dy=20) in GQIS 3 the first cell begins from the upper left corner and continues to the bottom of the grid  as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Is there any way to define the way that the id cells are located? Is there any plugin in QGIS? In fact, I want to begin from the lower left corner and continue to the east (as MapInfo does) as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a new layer with the re-ordered ID

Run the grid tool as you currently do.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query.

```sql
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  ST_MinY(geometry) asc, ST_MinX(geometry) asc) as newID
FROM Grid
```

you can replace the layer name (`Grid`) with the true name. If you don't want to have the old `id` field and the new `newID` field, replace `*` by the list of field name from `Grid` you want.

The query gets all rows from the `Grid` layer, then order each polygon by Y and X and generate a new sequential row number.

[image]

Comment: I tried this in QGIS3 but it gives the following error: "Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  ST_MinY(geometry) asc, ST_MinX(geometry) asc) as newID FROM Grid: 1 - near "(": syntax error".

Comment: @nat it works under 3.4.5 (LTR), which has spatialite 4.3 (`help menu`, `about`). The window function was introduced in spatialite 3.25

Comment: Thank you a lot! I installed 3.4.6(LTR) on a MAC OS and it worked.

Comment: I've tried this and I get mixed results - sometimes it appears the resulting grid ignores the second sorting order expression (i.e. ST_MinX) and only orders by the first. This occurs even if you try to alter the second condition (i.e., changing ````ST_MinX(geom)asc```` to ````ST_MaxX(geom)desc````, or the desc/asc's flipped)