# Create new grid based on another grid (shapefile) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector-grid

I have an shapefile of the historic grid Messtischblatt which is a CRS formerly used in Germany for the topographic map at a scale of 1:25,000. The CRS is OGC:CRS84 - WGS 84 (CRS84)

[image]

I want to further divide the cells for my new grid so I have 4 new Quadrants for each existing Quadrant.

I tried to measure the length and width one cell and divide it by 2. But the new grid obviously doesn't align with the old grid.

[image: Shapefile of MTB]

I have related the extent of the new grid to the extent of the original grid.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386664/creating-nested-grid-in-qgis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating nested grid in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386664/creating-nested-grid-in-qgis)