# QGIS 3.16 :Vector grid number generation

Tags: qgis-3, vector-grid

I would like to number my grid cells from Northwest to Southeast. I tested a formula in the field calculator found in this post: [Vector grid id generation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361803/vector-grid-id-generation/361838#361838).

But the problem is that I would like to have the number "9" instead of the number "10". So I want a series of continuous numbers. I can't do it manually because I have many of layers. Do you know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor change from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/317621/84870) leads to this:

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query.

```sql
select *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  ST_MinY(geometry) desc, ST_MinX(geometry) asc) as newID
FROM Grid
```

Replace the layer name (`Grid`) with the real name of your layer. If you don't want to have the old `id` field and the new `newID` field, replace `*` by the list of field name from `Grid` you want.

The query gets all rows from the `Grid` layer, then orders each polygon by Y (from northern to southern) and X (West to East) and generates a new sequential row number.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your help JGH. But I get an error :  "HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: @Demonshine Make sure you have used the proper layer name, or the proper geometry field name (if yours comes from a DB it might have a different name)

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is it possible to do the same thing on hundreds of files at once? Maybe using the modelbuilder?