# Generating horizontally ordered ids for irregular grid

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, vector-grid

How can I generate ids for an irregular shaped grid that increase from west to east and north to south (left to right, top to bottom)?

I've tried using [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361803/vector-grid-id-generation) and it almost works, but it does not work for an odd shaped grid - only symmetrical ones.

In the included image, the algorithm placed 9 below 8 instead of below 4 where it should be.

My Python code attempts to sort the rectangles horizontally instead of generating ids, but it is the same idea.

```
def sorted_horizontally(self):
    ...snip...
    faps_centroids = {k: v.geometry().centroid().asPoint() for k, v in faps.items()}
    centroids = []
    for k, v in faps_centroids.items():
        centroids.append( (v.x(), v.y()) )

    # X COORDINATE OPERATIONS
    min_centroid = min(centroids, key = lambda x: x[0])
    max_centroid = max(centroids, key = lambda x: x[0])
    min_x_centroid = min_centroid[0]
    max_x_centroid = max_centroid[0]
    x_centroids = [i[0] for i in centroids]
    x_set = set(x_centroids)
    distinct_x = len(x_set)
    range_x_centroid = max_x_centroid - min_x_centroid

    # Y COORDINATE OPERATIONS
    y_min_centroid = min(centroids, key = lambda x: x[1])
    y_max_centroid = max(centroids, key = lambda x: x[1])
    min_y_centroid = y_min_centroid[1]
    max_y_centroid = y_max_centroid[1]
    y_centroids = [i[1] for i in centroids]
    y_set = set(y_centroids)
    distinct_y = len(y_set)
    range_y_centroid = max_y_centroid - min_y_centroid

    # X VALUES
    x_values = []
    for k, v in faps_centroids.items():
        value = round( (v.x() - min_x_centroid) / (range_x_centroid/ distinct_x ) )
        x_values.append(value)
    x_values_set = sorted(list(set(x_values)))
    row_dict = {}
    for k, v in faps_centroids.items():
        value = round( (v.x() - min_x_centroid) / (range_x_centroid/ distinct_x ) )
        row_dict[k] = x_values_set.index(value) + 1
    row_dict = {k:v for k, v in sorted(row_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])}

    # Y VALUES
    col_dict = {}
    y_values = []
    for k, v in faps_centroids.items():
        value = round ( (max_y_centroid - v.y()) / (range_y_centroid / distinct_y) )
        y_values.append(value)
    y_values_set = sorted(list(set(y_values)))
    for k, v in faps_centroids.items():
        value = round ( (max_y_centroid - v.y()) / (range_y_centroid / distinct_y) )
        col_dict[k] = y_values_set.index(value) + 1
    col_dict = {k:v for k, v in sorted(col_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])}

    # BOTH X, Y
    final_dict = {}
    for k, v in col_dict.items():
        for kk, vv in row_dict.items():
            if k == kk:
                final_dict[k] = (vv, v)

    final_sort = sorted(final_dict, key = lambda k: (final_dict[k][1], final_dict[k][0]))
    return final_sort
```

[image]

Comment: here is a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404177/qgis-3-16-vector-grid-number-generation/404178#404178) using a virtual layer instead of python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It should work if your data is not rotated. I had to round the centroid values to zero decimals, you might have to play around with number of decimals if it doesnt work as expected:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

idfield = 'gridid' #The integer field to store grid ids in, add before executing
features = [f for f in layer.getFeatures()] #List all features
features.sort(key=lambda x: (-round(x.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y()), round(x.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x()))) #Sort the list by negative y and positive x centroid coordinates

ix = layer.fields().indexOf(idfield) #Find the index of idfield
attributemap = {f.id():{ix:e} for e,f in enumerate(features, 1)} #Number the features with enumerate
#{1: {5: 1}, 217: {5: 2},... 270: {5: 177}, 288: {5: 178}} Feature 1 will get grid id 1 in field 5, feature 288 id 178

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap) #Change/save the values
```

[image]